# Image rotation animation causes the image to move

Tags: swiftui

I want an image to rotate in place but the code I've written makes the image rotate but also move to a new place in the view. What am I doing wrong? I feel like I've tried everything:

```
struct loadingView: View {
    @State private var spinArrow = false   // Spinning Motion
    @State private var dismissArrow = false   // Opacity 1 - 0
    @State private var displayBorder = false   // StrokeBorder (lineWidth) 64 - 5
    @State private var displayCheckmark = false  // Trimpath from 1 - 0

    var body: some View {
                ZStack {
                    Image("arrowtocircle").resizable()
                        .frame(width:50, height: 50)
                        .rotationEffect(.degrees(spinArrow ? 720 : -360))
                        .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 2))
                        .onAppear() {
                            self.spinArrow.toggle()
                        }

                 }.frame(width: 500, height:500)
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not cause the image to move to a new place. Some other part of your code is doing that. Can you share other relevant parts?

Comment: @sElanthiraiyan - thank you for your reply! That's what I thought. I thought I was going crazy. I have updated my original post with full code excluding commented out parts. I just tested the code and it still moves my image diagonally whilst rotating

Comment: Check the place where you are using "loadingView". The updated code won't move the image as well.

Comment: @sElanthiraiyan I'm not using loadingView yet. I was just previewing it whilst writing the code for it and that's what the preview on the canvas shows - the image moving diagonally